# Using Twitter4j Daily Trends?

Tags: java, twitter

i've been working on a small program where I want to read in trending twitter topics and store them in a database. Currently I am using the twitter4j getDailyTrends() method, but getting strange results.

The code I currently have is:

```
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        ResponseList<Trends> dailyTrends;

        dailyTrends = twitter.getDailyTrends();

        System.out.println();

        // Print the trends.
        for (Trends trends : dailyTrends) {
                    System.out.println("As of : " + trends.getAsOf());
                      for (Trend trend : trends.getTrends()) {
                            System.out.println(" " + trend.getName());
                       }
        }
```

However, when the program runs, it shows the same list of trends 24 times. I have tried running the program on different days, however the list is always identical, no matter what day I run the program on.

I have also tried passing the getDailyTrends() method the current date and achieved the same results.

Would appreciate any help with this, it's driving me crazy. :)

EDIT: The result set I keep getting is displaying the twitter trends from 25.04.2012. And no matter when I run the program, or what date I give it - I get these same results.

EDIT2: OK so this has been bugging me all day, I eventually found the example code provided by twitter4j themselves for reading trends. I ran their code instead of mine, and I am having the same issue. The trends are a few weeks old, and never change. Has anyone actually managed to get this method working before?

Answer (score 15):

```
getPlaceTrends(int woeid)
```

Returns the top 10 trending topics for a specific **WOEID**, if trending information is available for it.

**woeid** - The Yahoo! Where On Earth ID of the location to return trending information for. Global information is available by using 1 as the **WOEID**.

You can get the WOEID's of different locations with the code below

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
ResponseList<Location> locations;
locations = twitter.getAvailableTrends();
System.out.println("Showing available trends");
for (Location location : locations) {
    System.out.println(location.getName() + " (woeid:" + location.getWoeid() + ")");
}
```

And then, you can get the present trends of a specific location using it's WOEID like below

```
Trends trends = twitter.getPlaceTrends(2295414);
for (int i = 0; i < trends.getTrends().length; i++) {
    System.out.println(trends.getTrends()[i].getName());
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I use twitter4j and this is my class to get trendings topics from location that you get as parameter, in this example "spain"

```
import twitter4j.Location;
import twitter4j.ResponseList;
import twitter4j.Trends;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;

public final class GetTrendingTopics {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

       ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setDebugEnabled(true).setOAuthConsumerKey("yourConsumerKey").setOAuthConsumerSecret("yourConsumerSecret").setOAuthAccessToken("yourOauthToken").setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("yourOauthTokenSecret");

        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
        Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

        ResponseList<Location> locations;
        locations = twitter.getAvailableTrends();

        Integer idTrendLocation = getTrendLocationId("spain");

        if (idTrendLocation == null) {
        System.out.println("Trend Location Not Found");
        System.exit(0);
        }

        Trends trends = twitter.getPlaceTrends(idTrendLocation);
        for (int i = 0; i < trends.getTrends().length; i++) {
        System.out.println(trends.getTrends()[i].getName());
        }

        System.exit(0);

    } catch (TwitterException te) {
        te.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Failed to get trends: " + te.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    }

    private static Integer getTrendLocationId(String locationName) {

    int idTrendLocation = 0;

    try {

        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setDebugEnabled(true).setOAuthConsumerKey("yourConsumerKey").setOAuthConsumerSecret("yourConsumerSecret").setOAuthAccessToken("yourOauthToken").setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("yourOauthTokenSecret");

        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
        Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

        ResponseList<Location> locations;
        locations = twitter.getAvailableTrends();

        for (Location location : locations) {
        if (location.getName().toLowerCase().equals(locationName.toLowerCase())) {
            idTrendLocation = location.getWoeid();
            break;
        }
        }

        if (idTrendLocation > 0) {
        return idTrendLocation;
        }

        return null;

    } catch (TwitterException te) {
        te.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Failed to get trends: " + te.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faintly remember but can you try the following

```
for (Trends trends : dailyTrends) {
                    System.out.println("As of : " + trends.getAsOf());

                     System.out.println(" " + trends.getTrendAt());

        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried what you suggested, and received the same list of trends I've been getting for days :(

Comment: In that case, I would suggest you to check which version of Twitter4J you are using and if it is not a version bug. I see a bug for getAsOf returning incorrect date. http://jira.twitter4j.org/browse/TFJ-613 If it is not listed, I suggest you to report a bug there

Comment: I was using the most recent stable version of twitter4j (2.2.5), I tried the newest snapshot version (2.2.6) and had the same issue again. I'm running out of ideas now.

Comment: Another update, I seem to be getting the trends from 25.04.2012, and I have been getting these same results for a few days. And still get the same results when adding a random date manually to the getDailyTrends() method.